# React Native for iOS: "network request failed" for one URL but not others

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

In my React Native app, I'm trying to make an API call with this code:

```
test = async () => {
    try {
      let a = await fetch('https://rxapitest.alliancepharmacygroup.ca:12345/', {
        method: 'GET',
      }).then(response => {
        console.log("success")
      })
    } catch(err) {
      console.log("error")
    }
  }
```

On Android this works fine. In Postman the request works fine. And when I replace the URL with `https://google.com` or something, it works fine. So it seems that the problem is with this particular URL for iOS only.

Here's my stacktrace:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace ?

Comment: Not a useful one. I've attached it in the original post though.

Comment: I remember I had problems with iOS if the url wasn’t SSL. I see it is a https url but if you missing SSL its something to look at.

Comment: @Müller What does it mean to be missing SSL? I heard the particular API might not have an SSL certificate, but I thought if the URL was https that that meant it did have an SSL certificate.

Comment: @Müller Also, it did work as of two months ago, so I'm not sure if Apple changed its policies around SSL or something.

Comment: If the server where you request the URL from has a missing SSL certificate iOS will not allow this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600625/ios-https-ssl-certificates, Have you tried the API from your browser or Postman? Do you get a "lock" top left of the browser or certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to add the NSAppTransportSecurity policy in info.plist?
Like that:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Yes I do have this. One thing someone mentioned about this particular API is that it doesn't have an SSL certificate. Do you know anything about how that works? I thought that since it's an HTTPS URL rather than HTTP that it must have an SSL certificate. Also, it did work as of two months ago, so I'm not sure if Apple changed its policies or something.

Comment: @gkeenley I tried with postman but it's not working for me. Neither on Android or iOS.

Comment: @gkeenley and for me it's more a sever side issue, than react native. Also for the ssl part, you can check the ssl certificate with you provider, because when you try to access to the url with your browser, it will tell you that it's not safe. Which means there is no ssl certificate or it's not well installed. (even if you try with HTTPS)

Comment: I've asked the provider about their SSL certificate. So you can still attempt to reach a URL via HTTPS even if they don't have SSL? How does that work?

Comment: @gkeenley you have a redirection to the http version, that why you can see the page on your browser